# android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference Retrofit

Tags: android, exception, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to implement an API with Retrofit in my Kotlin Android project. This API is yet used in the project in another activity and it works. The actual situation is just a bit differente. I'm trying to implement this API in an activity where I open a webview and at the callback of of the JS I call the retrofit instance and the API.

In this case the API doesn't start and I receive an error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Any idea related to this problem?
Thanks

I've checked all the objects linked to the API to prevent all null pointers.
I've also tried to call the api on `UiThread` but nothing helped.

```
//this is the request creation
override fun callMonthlySavingApi(response: ChangeMonthlySavingResponse) {
        iView.showLoader()
        val request = UserSettingsRequest.RequestBuilder()

        request.monthlySaving = response.value

        interactor.updateMonthlySaving(request.createRequestParams(), this)
    }

//this is the api implementation
 override fun updateMonthlySaving(
        request: UserSettingsRequest,
        listener: ChangeMonthlySavingMVP.ChangeMonthlySavingModel.onUpdateMonthlySavingListener
    ) {
        val response: Single<UserSettingsResponse> = apiClient.updateUser(
            ApiUtils.getEndpoint(ApiUtils.ApiKey.POST_UPDATE_USER_SETTINGS),
            request.getMapRequest()
        )

        response.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { data: UserSettingsResponse? ->
                    if (data != null && !data.checkError()) {
                        listener.onUpdateMonthlySavingFinish()
                    } else {
                        listener.onUpdateMonthlySavingInternalError(data?.error?.message ?: "Error")
                    }
                },
                { throwable: Throwable? ->
//here i receive the error and it seems linked to nothing
//ERROR:
//Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object //android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null //object reference

                    if (throwable != null) {
                        listener.onUpdateMonthlySavingError(throwable)
                    }
                }
            )
    }
```

This is the error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532507/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java-lang-object-android-content-context-getsy)

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the complete stack trace, not just the error message.