# Using a Fragment as the Context in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-context

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/E6vE8fqQPTE)

I have a project that uses the **Sidebar Navigation**, so I have one `MainActivity` and multiple Fragments. At ~6:20 into the video, you can see the following code:

```
PersonListAdapter adapter = new PersonListAdapter(
                                    this,  
                                    R.layout.adapter_view_layout, 
                                    peopleList);
```

The constructor for the PersonListAdapter Class is:

```
public PersonListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Attacks> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mResource = resource;
    }
```

The problem lies with Context.

- If I use the word "**this**", there is a red line.
- If I replace
  "this" with "**getActivity()**", there is no red line, but the app
  crashes when I run it.
- I've also tried "**this.getContext()**" and "**this.getActivity()**"
- I have also tried replacing "this" with "**getActivity().getApplicationContext()**", and the app crashes.

The tutorial uses MainActivity.java, but my code is in FragmentCharacters.java. I don't know what I'm supposed to write in place of "**this**", or if I need to change something in the PersonListAdapter class for Context.

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace of the error? getActivity() should never return null between the onAttach() and onDetach() phases of the Fragment lifecycle.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything close to what you may be wanting me to find.

I've added a try/catch block with the catch as (Exception e) e.printStackTrace(). 
I don't know where to find the information that get's printed out. 

And I've tried Analyze > Analyze Stacktrace, but all I'm seeing is the original code. Nothing extra.

In the Run console down at the bottom, it does say "Skipped 98 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

I'm new to Java/Android Studio. I'm just following the tutorial. Anything "extra" right now, is over my head.

Comment: System messages can be seen by clicking on the "Logcat" tab down the bottom, near the Run console. Have this tab open when you run the app and look for a dump of text with blue lines linking to lines of your code where your error is thrown. Also make note of what the error type is.

Comment: This is what I'm seeing in Logcat:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: me.com.testproject, PID: 23680
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068530/errorattempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-java-lang-object-android-content-context

Comment: Yeah, make sure you are calling your getActivity() within onActivityCreated() or later.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a Fragment as a Context, because Fragment doesn't inherit from Context.

However, if you consult the [Fragment lifecycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4eF5.png), you can see that the Fragment has access to its host Activity at any time between the lifecycle callbacks OnActivityCreated() and onDestroyView(). If you try to access the Activity before OnActivityCreated(), for example, it will probably return null.

So make sure you are calling getActivity() from within onActivityCreated() or later, which will make sure your Activity is available.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE, I Provided a Case Example inside the Code Snippets as well, and I chose "FragmentName" as Fragment name for example.

First Look at This Fragment Structure.
I Added [mAdapter] in Both `onCreate` and `onCreateView`

And I Added `FragmentName.this` for the Forth argument

The Reason is, You can send data from The Adapter to Other Activities with it, for Example `FragmentName.mAdapter.getLayoutPosition()`

But, Let's assume We have an ImageView which is In MainActivity and we want to use it in our Adapter, So let's Establish an ImageView In our Fragment as well, Notice I Declared the ImageView Inside `onCreate`

And, For Another Example, Let's Assume we Have a Public Void at the End of our Fragment as Well, It can be Literally Anything. I Named it `ExampleClass`

```js
/////////FIRST TAKE A LOOK AT FRAGMENT//////////
public class FragmentName extends Fragment {

  PersonListAdapter adapter;
  ImageView imageView; // For Example thi ImageView is from MainActivity

  public FragmentName() {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    adapter = new PersonListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.adapter_view_layout, peopleList, FragmentName.this);

    imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    // This Imageview is in Another Activity, Like MainActivity
    // So we Need to Find it Using 'getActivity()'

    ...
  }


  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    adapter = new PersonListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.adapter_view_layout, peopleList, FragmentName.this);

  }

}

  public void ExampleClass(int color, ...) {
  ...
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Now, Let's take this Example into our Adapter as well, to Show how it can be Used.

But, In the Adapter Use [FragmentName], Instead of [Fragment] like Below:

```js
///////////NOW INSIDE YOUR ADAPTER/////////////
  public class PersonListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < PersonListAdapter.myViewHolder > {

      FragmentName myFragment; // SEE WHAT HAPPENDED HERE?

      ...

      public PersonListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList < Attacks > objects, FragmentName fragment) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mResource = resource;
        this.myFragment = fragment
      }


      @Override
      public PersonListAdapter.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      
      // Example use of myFragment
      // Lets Execute ExmpleClass inside the Fragment
      myFragment.ExampleClass(int color, ...);
      
      // Let's Use the ImageView from MainActivity Here
      myFragment.imageView.setImageRresource(...);
      
      
        ...
      }
      ...

      // YOU CAN NOW USE "myFragment" As a Context In your Adapter
```

The Good Part about this is That You can Use Fragment As CONTEXT in Your PersonListAdapter

Update: The second Code, onCreateViewHolder is wrong, it has to be inside a ClickListener in ViewHolder or onBindViewHolder

Comment: Hello there, thank you for the reply.
I feel like the solution is HERE, but I'm still getting an error.

I have added the changes, there are no spelling or syntax errors.

Fragment fragment is declared.
The constructor for PersonListAdapter has been updated with 4 arguments, the fourth argument being "Fragment fragment". 
And "this.myFragment - fragment" has been added within the constructor.

However, when I add "this" as the 4th argument to new PersonListAdapter(1,2,3,4) - I get a red line: the error exists in the 4th argument.
.

Comment: Ahhh, Good thing you pointed out the error, My code is Gonna be wrong because Each Fragment has a Different Name that already been extended to Fragment Library. I'm gonna Fix and Update the Code Right Away

Comment: Hi Nicholette, I Updated the answer, It Looks Long, But It's All The Same, Just Look at it Carefully, It's So Easy to implement. I Hope you do very well with this

Comment: You're now passing both a Fragment AND a Context into the adapter, which doesn't address the issue of the Context being null when the adapter is constructed, and introduces unnecessary coupling.

Comment: This code Is an Example, I just Said it, don't tell me you want to just copy paste codes. Obviously you must alter the example yourself

Comment: It is code that in principle is error-prone and violates programming principles such as encapsulation and non-redundancy. It doesn't fix the crash, either.

Comment: In the code onCreateViewHolder is wrong, must be either onItemClickListener or some form of item Click in onBindViewHolder. That's it.

Comment: The issue here is that you are passing a Fragment and a Context separately to the adapter when they are both doing the same thing (accessing View hierarchy).

Comment: It's not going to be a problem, both Contexts are the same, It's useless using two Context but the point is, The Fragment isn't just a Context used in the Adapter, It's also a Bridge you can use to execute Fragment codes inside your adapter. If you are using the Adapter in an Activity, then you wouldn't need Fragment as a Context at all.
But with That Fragment in the Adapter, You can even take a component, an object and even an entire class out of the MainActivity, Pass it to Fragment, and Use it in the Adapter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164661/discussion-between-urgentx-and-shahin).

Comment: I just want you to know that I was not the person that down voted this, and I really appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me.

Comment: Hello nicholette, thank u so much, but just be aware every time a Fragment loads an adapter, it's gonna load the codes we introduced by using Fragment inside the adapter, it can cause some expensive Processing, It will make the adapters heavy, Just use it as little as possible and always use it in a ClickListener so you know it's not gonna execute out of place and time. I've used it in some apps, it's wasn't that big of a deal, but I'm testing this on different types of situations.